# Possible to run applications from the cloud?

Tags: installation, cloud

When installing Ubuntu, I made the partition really small. I would like to know if applications like *vlc* or *Clementine* be installed and run from the cloud?

Comment: Sorry, your question is a little unclear. Are you asking how to run programs over the Internet, or how to store files elsewhere, or something else?

Comment: Yes, that question is incomprehensible. You need to rewrite it.

Comment: You can ofcourse also increase your partition ;=)

Comment: In theory, yes, I think. In practice it would require ssh/smb/ftp/http/whatever access to an online server, some creative symlinking, and probably a good FUSE driver.

Answer (score 1):

You may run a full Ubuntu desktop in the cloud, however multimedia apps will suffer because of network latency and throughput

http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2010/11/show-off-ubuntu-desktop-on-cloud/

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to run some applications from a dropbox share before (I can't see why you couldn't do the same with UbuntuOne). I did this for an experiment but it did work, albeit slow!

For example, if you have your dropbox share linked to ~/dropbox and you wanted to free up space, you could do this by moving your main vlc /usr/share/vlc directory to you dropbox and create a symbolic link back to your /usr/share directory.

eg: `sudo ln -s /home/youruser/dropbox/vlc /usr/share/`

But at the end of the day, I think this isn't a great solution and you would probably be far better off running some of the apps off a usb stick if storage is an issue.

Comment: The problem, though, is that DropBox and Ubuntu One still store and sync locally.